# For $q\in (0.5,1)$ why is there $c>0$ such that $f_k(x):=kx^k \leq c q^k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, power-series, geometric-series

In a question I am doing, I am considering the functions $$f_k(x) :=  kx^k$$ ($k\in \mathbb{N}$) on the interval $(-0.5,0)$.

In the solution it says:

pick $q \in (0.5,1)$ and then there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for $|x|\leq 0.5$
$$f_k(x)\leq cq^k$$ for all $k$.

why is $q$ chosen in this specific range and how do we know such a constant $c$ exists?

Comment: You wrote and then deleted "I am trying to understand why the absolute value of the partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k$ are bounded above by a integrable function $g$ that is independent of $n$". I don't know why you deleted this, but I think that this is important if you want to know why $q$ is chosen in the range. Are you still trying to understand why $|S_n|$ is bounded above by $g$?

Comment: I thought there was too much unnecessary detail that people might not read it. Yes I’m still trying to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f'_k(x)=k^2x^{k-1}$.

- If $k$ is even, then we see that $f'_k(x)\lt 0$ for $-0.5\le x\lt 0$ and that $f'_k(x)\gt 0$ for $0\lt x\le 0.5$. So, we get $f_k(x)\le k(\pm 0.5)^k=k(0.5)^k$.
- If $k$ is odd, then we see that $f'_k(x)\gt 0$. So, we get $f_k(x)\le k(0.5)^k$.

So, for every $k$ and for $|x|\le 0.5$, we get $$f_k(x)\le k(0.5)^k$$

Finally, we can take $c=k$ to have
$$f_k(x)\le k(0.5)^k\le cq^k$$

---

> why is $q$ chosen in this specific range

I think that the reason why $0.5\lt q$ is that if $0.5\lt q$, then we can easily get $c$ such that $f_k(x)\le k(0.5)^k\le cq^k$.

We can have
$$|S_n|=\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)\bigg|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f_k(x)|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}kq^k=\frac{q(nq^{n+1}-(n+1)q^n+1)}{(1-q)^2}$$
if $q\not=1$. (If $q=1$, then $|S_n|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ which depends on $n$.)

I think that the reason why $q\lt 1$ is that if $q\lt 1$, then we can say that

$$|S_n|\le\frac{q(nq^{n+1}-(n+1)q^n+1)}{(1-q)^2}\lt \frac{q}{(1-q)^2}$$
which is independent of $n$ where we have used $nq^{n+1}-(n+1)q^n+1\lt 1$ (which is equivalent to $(1-q)n+1\gt 0$ which is true).

Comment: Thank you for even trying to answer the preedited question